# INPUT_FILTER in Doxygen adding to mainpage

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to use the mainpage functionality of doxygen to specify what will be displayed on the index.html page.

I currently have set in my doxyfile:

```
INPUT                  = README.md /path/to/my/project/files
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = README.md
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.proto *.md
INPUT_FILTER           = "python /path/to/my/docs/proto2cpp.py"
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = *.py
```

Doxygen is finding the README.md and adding it to the index.html page, but it is **also** adding the proto2cpp.py file to the index page. I just want the README.md text. You can see the [proto2cpp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proto2cpp/) script here, the README just has a couple of lines of text like:

## test

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the proto2cpp the file with all the information? I don't see e.g. README.md  and the Doxyfile is not the described file. I tried to manipulate a bit these file, i.e. created my own Doxyfile based on hat is in this report and copied README to README.md but I didn't see the indicated behavior.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using (current version is 1.8.11) and if the problem persist can you show the used code here or file a bug report (http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/trouble.html#bug_reports) or in your cross posted message in the doxygen forum (http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/INPUT-FILTER-being-added-to-mainpage-tp7593.html)